# Python limited API: howto set __module__ attribute of extension type

Tags: python, abi

When using the 'limited API' the structure of PyTypeObject is not available. So, you can't define statically allocated type objects.

For dynamically allocated type objects (aka heap types) you specify the name of the type via PyType_Spec.name.
The doc says: "*For dynamically allocated type objects, this should just be the type name, and the module name explicitly stored in the type dict as the value for key '__module__'.*"

But there is no type slot for setting PyTypeObject.tp_dict. So, howto set the module name?

You can do that dynamically after the type is created. But that gives a "*DeprecationWarning: builtin type ... has no __module__ attribute*".

Answer (score 1):

The `__module__` is computed from the type's `tp_name`, which should look like `"module_name.TypeName"`. When creating heap types in C code, `tp_name` is specified through `PyType_Spec.name`.

The `tp_name` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_name) say something contradictory:

> For dynamically allocated type objects, this should just be the type name, and the module name explicitly stored in the type dict as the value for key `'__module__'`.

but those docs appear to be wrong for the case of calls like [`PyType_FromModuleAndSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/type.html#c.PyType_FromModuleAndSpec) that dynamically allocate type objects in C code. Examining the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.2/Objects/typeobject.c#L3069) shows that it expects the module name to be part of `tp_name`:

```
    /* Set type.__module__ */
    if (_PyDict_GetItemIdWithError(type->tp_dict, &PyId___module__) == NULL) {
        if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
            goto fail;
        }
        s = strrchr(spec->name, '.');
        if (s != NULL) {
            int err;
            modname = PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize(
                    spec->name, (Py_ssize_t)(s - spec->name));
            if (modname == NULL) {
                goto fail;
            }
            err = _PyDict_SetItemId(type->tp_dict, &PyId___module__, modname);
            Py_DECREF(modname);
            if (err != 0)
                goto fail;
        } else {
            if (PyErr_WarnFormat(PyExc_DeprecationWarning, 1,
                    "builtin type %.200s has no __module__ attribute",
                    spec->name))
                goto fail;
        }
    }
```

and examining [uses](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.2/Modules/zlibmodule.c#L1332) of `PyType_Spec` in the standard library show that the module name goes in `tp_name`:

```
static PyType_Spec Comptype_spec = {
    "zlib.Compress",
    sizeof(compobject),
    0,
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,
    Comptype_slots
};
```

Note that despite `PyType_FromModuleAndSpec` taking a module as an argument, this module is not used to set `__module__`.